# print text within some quotes in Java scanner(more info down in the body)

Tags: java, input, output, java.util.scanner

I am trying to replicate a programming language(Python's syntax for example) in Java.
I am trying to get user input like "print("some text")". If the input contains print, the text in the parenthesis will output. It is for a personal project that I've craved for the last few months and now I'm feeling a bit confident but I'm stuck at this part for now. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the field of language design! Parsing syntax is an entire area of study in and of itself. There are popular libraries in almost any conceivable language to help with the task ([ANTLR](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4) being one of the more well-known ones). Or you can take the plunge and try to learn parsing yourself. [Recursive descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) is a good beginner parsing algorithm, and if you like what you see you can move on into more advanced things like LR(1) afterward.